# Boost Spirit Karma multiple optionals

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma, boost-optional

I'm seeing an error that I'm not seeing the resolution to.  First, the relevant code:

```
namespace C {

    struct RangeEntry {
        size_t byte;
        boost::optional<size_t> bit;
    };

    struct Range {
        RangeEntry firstPart;
        boost::optional<RangeEntry> secondPart;
        boost::optional<size_t> shift;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    C::RangeEntry,
    (size_t, byte)
    (boost::optional<size_t>, bit)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    C::Range,
    (C::RangeEntry , firstPart)
    (boost::optional<C::RangeEntry> , secondPart)
    (boost::optional<size_t> , shift)
)

... Declare the rules ...

karma::rule<Iterator, C::Range()> range;
karma::rule<Iterator, C::RangeEntry()> range_part;

... Define rules ...

range_part %= no_delimit[ulong_ << -(lit(":") << ulong_)];
range %= no_delimit[range_part << -(lit("-") << range_part)] << -(lit("<<") << ulong_);
```

At the `range %=` part, I get the compile error

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:504:30: error:
invalid operands to binary expression 
('C::RangeEntry' and 'C::RangeEntry')
    return floor(num / spirit::traits::pow10<T>(exp));
                 ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm guessing it's trying to match a RangeEntry to the ulong_ rule, but I can't figure out why?  What am I missing?

Comment: Just a [hint](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48eacn$0).

Comment: The absense of RangeEntry from the question makes it near unanswerable. Next time, make sure you include a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)!

Comment: @llonesmiz You might be interested to know that there is [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) now, which allows you to pipe the output through `c++filt` for much easier demangling: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3089fcde920f97df82b0af253bac4525-8a198f2201fdad384733f7124c65aa0e

Comment: @sehe That is really interesting, thanks.

Comment: @sehe sorry, I forgot to include that (no reason why I couldn't have).  your "fantasized" example was pretty much spot on, though.  (my own struct of unsigned long and optional<unsigned long>, instead of a pair).

Comment: I've included RangeEntry for the benefit of future readers.  AFAIK, it's equivalent to sehe's version as far as karma is concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `no_delimit` directive is regrouping your exposed fusion sequences. Note that the following does compile:

```
    range %= range_part << -(lit("-") << range_part) << -(lit("<<") << ulong_);
```

or even

```
    range %= no_delimit[range_part << -(lit("-") << range_part) << -(lit("<<") << ulong_)];
```

AFAICT the rules are defined without delimiter, so the no_delimit should be redundant here anyway.

---

I have "fantasized" a RangeEntry type just to make it a selfcontained sample:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

namespace C {
    typedef std::pair<unsigned long, boost::optional<unsigned long> > RangeEntry;

    struct Range {
        RangeEntry firstPart;
        boost::optional<RangeEntry> secondPart;
        boost::optional<size_t> shift;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    C::Range,
    (C::RangeEntry , firstPart)
    (boost::optional<C::RangeEntry> , secondPart)
    (boost::optional<size_t> , shift)
    );

//... Declare the rules ...

int main()
{
    typedef char* Iterator;
    karma::rule<Iterator, C::Range()> range;
    karma::rule<Iterator, C::RangeEntry()> range_part;

    //... Define rules ...

    using namespace karma;
    range_part %= no_delimit[ulong_ << -(lit(":") << ulong_)];
    range %= no_delimit[range_part << -(lit("-") << range_part) << -(lit("<<") << ulong_)];
}
```